# Can't add a picture from my computer to css styling

Tags: html, css, image, styles

I can't add a file from my computer to use for my background on my website. Can only use URLs. How can I get the local file added?

[image: Can't add local file on Line 18]

Comment: use a image hosting service like `imgur`, and get a link that you can paste inside `url()` https://imgur.com/upload

Comment: Please dont post text as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are setting width to `100%` instead use a `px` or `rem` value.`100%` means 100% of its parent & i assume it doesn't have a parent.

```css
 div {
            height: 320px;
            width: 240px;
            background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/-Insert_image_here-.svg);
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
```

```html
<div></div>
```